# ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. Change the type to string but not yet resolved

Tags: python, pandas, merge

```
import pandas as pd

SOheader_df = pd.read_excel("E:\My IDEA Documents\IDEA Projects\Sales_systemcontrols\Source Files.ILB\VBAK_SOheaderdata.XLSX")

KNVV_df = pd.read_excel("E:\My IDEA Documents\IDEA Projects\Sales_systemcontrols\Source Files.ILB\KNVV.xlsx" ,usecols=['Customer', 'Sales Organization', 'Distribution Channel', 'Division', 'Cust.Pric.Procedure', 'Acct Assmt Grp Cust.'])

# Change the data type of Sold to Party

KNVV_df['Customer'].astype(str).dtype

SOheader_df['Cust.Pric.Procedure'] = SOheader_df.merge(KNVV_df, how='inner', left_on='Sold-ToParty', right_on='Customer', indicator='True')
```

Sold to party was in `int64` and `Customer` was in `object`. Hence type changed but problem continue.

Answer (score 0):

Error message suggests columns dtypes on which you are merging differ.

You can try to cast `Customer` column to `int` so dtypes match. Note that in order to change a column dtype, you need to re-assign the original column to the casted column.

```
KNVV_df['Customer'] = KNVV_df['Customer'].astype(int)
```